# Виды подчинительных связей

Tags: синтаксис

В СПП предложениях выделяют три вида связи: последовательное подчинение,однородное подчинение и параллельное подчинение.

А как быть с предложениями, в которых объединены сочинение и подчинение?
Напр.

**[Илья Андреевич понимал], (что (если не собрать яблоки до наступления холодов), то весь урожай погибнет), но обстоятельства не щадили его].**
Это предложение с разными видами связи. В нем есть части с последовательным подчинением. Есть и сочинительная связь. Как производить разбор в таких случаях? К чему относится сочинительная связь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***{[Илья Андреевич понимал], (что (если не собрать яблоки до наступления холодов), то весь урожай погибнет)}, но [обстоятельства не щадили его].***

Сложное многокомпонентное предложение; ведущая связь — сочинительная.  Сочинительным противительным союзом ***но*** связаны простое и сложноподчинённое предложения.

Comment: Под простым вы имеете в виду "обстоятельства не щадили его"?

Comment: Да, "обстоятельства не щадили его".

Answer (score 3):

Бывают сложные предложения с разными видами связи. Конкретная их характеристика зависит от того, как части связаны между собой.

К сожалению, пунктуация не предполагает способов четкого разделения фраз в такой сложной иерархии: разделяющие их запятые все выглядят абсолютно одинаково. Поэтому при чтении такого предложения приходится опираться на контекст.

В частности, рассмотрим ваш пример:

*Илья Андреевич понимал, что если не собрать яблоки до наступления холодов, то весь урожай погибнет, но обстоятельства не щадили его.*

Здесь можно явно выделить следующие части предложения:

- *Илья Андреевич понимал*;
- *не собрать яблоки до наступления холодов*;
- *весь урожай погибнет*;
- *обстоятельства не щадили его*.

Также имееются следующие средства связи частей предложения:

- подчинительное *что*;
- подчинительное *если, то*;
- сочинительное *но*.

*Обстоятельства не щадили его* является второй частью сложносочиненного предложения, присоединяемой сочинительным союзом *но*. Логически, из контекста, мы можем предположить, что *его* в этой фразе относится к *Илье Андреевичу*. Единственной альтернативой был бы *урожай*, но вряд ли тут такая трактовка.

Остальные части предложения вряд ли являются придаточными к *обстоятельства не щадили его*, поэтому делаем вывод, что последний фрагмент является простым предложением, а всё предложение целиком является сложносочиненным.

Первая часть сложносочиненного предложения включает 3 составляющих. Значит, она сама является сложным предложением. У нас остались только подчинительные союзы, поэтому как бы связи внутри неё не были организованы, мы уже можем сказать, что она является сложноподчиненной.

Главной частью является *Илья Андреевич понимал*: от неё задается вопрос к придаточной, присоединяемой подчинительным союзом *что*.

Составное *если, то* присоединяет придаточную часть *не собрать яблоки до наступления холодов* к главной части *весь урожай погибнет*. Это означает, что *не собрать яблоки до наступления холодов* относится к другой придаточной, а не к главной части *Илья Андреевич понимал*. Поэтому здесь не может быть ни параллельного, ни однородного подчинения, только последовательное.

Таким образом получаем сложносочиненное предложение, первая часть которого является сложноподчиненной с последовательным подчинением.

Comment: Встречный вопрос. А вы уверены, что это удачная идея, разбирать "от противного"? *Остальные части предложения вряд ли являются придаточными* - странная идея. *Логически, из контекста, мы можем предположить, что его в этой фразе относится к Илье Андреевичу* - только логически?  *Поэтому здесь не может быть ни параллельного, ни однородного подчинения* - а что, кто-то может всерьез рассматривать такое?

Answer (score 1):

> [Илья Андреевич понимал], (что (если не собрать яблоки до наступления
> холодов), то весь урожай погибнет), но обстоятельства не щадили его].

Вы тут, конечно, запутались со скобками, но мысль понятна.
В целом вы правильно разобрали предложение.

В целом предложение сложносочиненное с союзом НО:

*Илья Андревич понимал, (...) но обстоятельства не щадили ...*

Первая часть этого сложносочиненного предложения преставляет собой сложноподчиненное предложение с союзом "что"

*...понимал,  что (...)*

> *Как производить разбор в таких случаях?*

Раньше в школе учили рисовать прямоугольнички разного уровня.
В нашем случае это примерно так:

**+----------+  НО +----------+**
**+----------+**  . . .  **+----------+**
. . . **|**
**+----------+  ЧТО +----------+**
**+----------+**  . . . . .  **+----------+**
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  **|**
. . . . . .  **ЕСЛИ +----------+ ТО  +----------+**
. . . . . . . . . . . .  **+----------+**  . . .  **+----------+**

> К чему относится сочинительная связь?

К двум составляющим основного предложения.

Comment: @JKlen Нет, просто не вычитал. Сложноподчиненная, конечно. Спасибо.